# PHP Required Once Error when opening file

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error from a Windows server:

> Warning: require_once(../../conf/config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in \WDP\DFS\30\6\3\2\3039591236\user\sites\5213291.site\www\webmap\inc\class\conf.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../conf/config.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in \WDP\DFS\30\6\3\2\3039591236\user\sites\5213291.site\www\webmap\inc\class\conf.php on line 2*******

This is a simple query to MYSQL table on a Windows server. I have the files in www/webmap. Here is the relevant part of the config.php

```
<?php
 require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/inc/class/csite.php');
 require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/inc/class/users.php');
 require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/inc/class/dbc.php');
 require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/inc/class/resize.php');
 require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/inc/class/func.php');
```

My understanding is that the config.php is found as I included:

`echo "Does file exist?". file_exists($file) ? 'true' : 'false';
echo "Is it readable?".is_readable($file) ? 'true' : 'false'; require_once $file;`

which returns "true, true"

Comment: What is not clear about the error message? The contents of `config.php` dont matter much if the file `config.php` failed to open.

Comment: Conn.php says it did open and connection to db was made: Connected successfully

Comment: What does it matter what `Conn.php` says? It is irrelevant to the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your program is located in this file.

> WDP\DFS\30\6\3\2\3039591236\user\sites\5213291.site\www\webmap\inc\class\conf.php

On line **2**...

```
require_once '../../conf/config.php';
```

Based on this error message, the file your program is looking for is this...

> WDP\DFS\30\6\3\2\3039591236\user\sites\5213291.site\www\webmap\conf\config.php

To fix your program, you need to make sure that your require_once function is properly pointing to the config.php file you're looking for.

---

**File Path Examples**

> \www\conf\config.php

```
require_once '../../../conf/config.php';
```

---

> \www\webmap\conf\config.php

```
require_once '../../conf/config.php';
```

---

> \www\webmap\inc\conf\config.php

```
require_once '../conf/config.php';
```

---

> \www\webmap\inc\class\conf\config.php

```
require_once 'conf/config.php';
```

---

If things are getting rough using ../'s, try finding your file from the root by beginning your path with a forward slash.

```
require_once '/webmap/inc/conf/config.php';
```

---

You can also try this to make sure you are reading from the proper relative directory:

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../conf/config.php';
```

---

**My final offer:**
Based on the file location's you've supplied in the comments, I can only recommend that you try one of these sets.

```
require_once '../../conf/config.php';
require_once '../conn.php';

require_once '/webmap/conf/config.php';
require_once '/webmap/inc/conn.php';

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/webmap/conf/config.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/webmap/inc/conn.php';
```

Comment: My understanding is that the config.php is found as I included .file_exists($file) and .is_readable($file) code, which returns true, true

Comment: You need to include this information in your question. We don't know anything about your directory structure, which file is called first, if the current directory is changed at any point etc.

Comment: What is the value of $file?

Comment: This is the file:   <?php
require_once('../../conf/config.php');
require_once('../../inc/conn.php');


echo "Does file exist?". file_exists($file) ? 'true' : 'false';
echo "Is it readable?".is_readable($file) ? 'true' : 'false';
require_once $file;

?>

Comment: Check my last example. Can you give the true location of conf.php, config.php and conn.php? We know conf.php is in www\webmap\inc\class\ but where are the other files located?

Comment: I've made one more addition to my suggestion based on these file paths. Where I've used $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], you might want to try echoing out those strings to see if its pointing to the proper file, if it fails.